# Perl comparing two name-value arrays

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to do a simple comparison of rows of two seperate name-value arrays in Perl (5.8.8), but can not find what I'm doing wrong. I seems that within a for keys

I have declared the two arrays:

```
my %array1;
my %array2;
```

I fill up the rows like this, to build name-value rows:

```
$array1{$name}=$value;
```

and array two contains rows with the same name (but possibly different values):

```
$array2{$name}=$value2;
```

Now, I compare the different values for every row in array 1 like this:

```
    for my $k(keys %array1) {
       if ($array1{$k} ne $array2{$k}) {
           .. more program logic
       }
```

But, it seems the second array is not defined within the for loop running over the 'keys' of the first array (if I insert a unless (defined $array2($k)) this hits, and when trying to use the $array2(k) anyhow, I get the error 'Use of uninitialized value'. I'm lost here. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%array1, \%array2;` before `for` loop to check what you have there. And btw, these are perl hashes, not arrays.

Comment: Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings`?  It sounds like you have a typo in a variable name.

Comment: Firstly, you don't have arrays, you have hashes. And secondly, your question is too vague to answer. Please create a short program that exhibits your problem and edit your question to include the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes, array of name-value pairs, associative arrays, yes. 
So I have implemented a hash-on-hash 2-dimensional associative array to keep everything within one 'structure', and all works fine. Still don't get what was wrong in the two seperate hashes approach, must have been some typo, but hey problem solved. 
Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could test for existence of key in %array2, like this:

```
for my $k(keys %array1) {
   if (!exists($array2{$k}) || $array1{$k} ne $array2{$k}) {
       .. more program logic
   }
```